# How to stream Vertx request directly to file via pipe

Tags: http, file-upload, vert.x

I am using Vertx. 4.0.3 and trying to stream a request body directly to a file. For that purpose I am using the following (Kotlin) code:

```kotlin
router.post("/upload").handler { ctx ->
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val response = ctx.response()
    val request = ctx.request()
    val fs = vertx.fileSystem()

    fs.open("data.bin", OpenOptions()) { res ->
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            val asyncFile = res.result()
            request.pipeTo(asyncFile).onComplete { writeResult ->
                if(writeResult.succeeded()) {
                    response.end("${System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime}")
                } else {
                    response.setStatusCode(500).end(res.cause().stackTraceToString())
                }
            }
        } else {
            response.setStatusCode(500).end(res.cause().stackTraceToString())
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting an exception like:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request has already been read
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest.checkEnded(Http1xServerRequest.java:628)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest.endHandler(Http1xServerRequest.java:334)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest.endHandler(Http1xServerRequest.java:60)
    at io.vertx.core.streams.impl.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:35)
    at io.vertx.core.streams.ReadStream.pipeTo(ReadStream.java:119)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.HttpServerRequestWrapper.pipeTo(HttpServerRequestWrapper.java:410)
    at fileupload.AppKt$main$2$1.handle(App.kt:60)
    at fileupload.AppKt$main$2$1.handle(App.kt)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$3.onSuccess(FutureImpl.java:124)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.lambda$emitSuccess$0(FutureBase.java:54)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Since I do nothing to the request I have no idea where my request is already read. Can someone please give me some insights into this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because by the time the callback of `fs.open` is invoked, the request has been fully read already.

You must pause the request before opening the file and resume it after:

```
router.post("/upload").handler { ctx ->
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val response = ctx.response()
    val request = ctx.request()
    val fs = vertx.fileSystem()

    // Pause
    request.pause()

    fs.open("data.bin", OpenOptions()) { res ->

        // Resume
        request.resume()

        if (res.succeeded()) {
            val asyncFile = res.result()
            request.pipeTo(asyncFile).onComplete { writeResult ->
                if(writeResult.succeeded()) {
                    response.end("${System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime}")
                } else {
                    response.setStatusCode(500).end(res.cause().stackTraceToString())
                }
            }
        } else {
            response.setStatusCode(500).end(res.cause().stackTraceToString())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Great. As a side note, in most cases, using the `BodyHandler` relieves you from maintaining such code.

Comment: Yes. I know about the body handler and usually I use that. But for this little experiment I wanted to avoid it, since (and maybe I am wrong with that) it stores the request body to disk before it allows me to process it. But I wanted to really stream, without hitting the disk early.

Answer (score 2):

Vert.x for Kotlin provide a equivalent set of suspend functions. In your case you may want to implement the equivalent `openAwait` and `pipeToAwait` functions in order to avoid the "callback hell". Now your code might look like this:

```
router.post("/upload").handler { ctx ->
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val response = ctx.response()
    val request = ctx.request()
    val fs = vertx.fileSystem()

    val asyncFile = fs.openAwait("data.bin", OpenOptions())
    val result = request.pipeToAwait(asyncFile)

    // code for sending http response
}
```